# Download Image and Send it to an API using multipart/form-data

Tags: node.js, image, request

I am trying to send a image from the internet to an API using `multipart/form-data`.

I was able to do this by saving the image in a temp folder using `request.pipe(fs.createWriteStream)` and upload using `fs.createReadStream`

But how can i do this without saving it in a temp folder?

I tried creating a new `request` and sending the body as a `new Buffer` but didn't work.

Extra information:

I am implementing the Telegram Bot API method sendPhoto: 
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto

I am using the request module for the integration:
https://github.com/request/request

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the request node library, you [can get binary content from the resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855015/getting-binary-content-in-node-js-using-request) setting `encoding: null` in `requestSettings`. So the binary content is stored in memory into an object (Buffer).

To send a photo using the [node-telegram-bot](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api#TelegramBot+sendPhoto), you will do:

```
var TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
var bot = new TelegramBot(token);

var requestSettings = {
    url: 'http://httpbin.org/image',
    encoding: null
};

request(requestSettings, function (error, response, buffer) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        bot.sendPhoto(chatId, buffer)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem and I resolved with the next code, using the request-promise library

```
    const rp = require('request-promise');

    const req = {
        'url': 'https://store.server.com',
        'json': true,
        'resolveWithFullResponse': true
    };

    req['formData'] = {
        media: rp.get('https://videourl.com')
    };
    return rp.post(req)
        .then(response => return response)
        .catch(error => return throw error);
```