# Error passing in request get data into graphicsmagick or imagemagick in node.js

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I'm changing my code to fetch a remote image from an http get instead of an s3 object and having some trouble with the data.  The data is not null and does seem to be an image binary - but am I sending in the wrong stream format or something - or sending an invalid format into the graphicsmagick constructor?

I get the error

```
{ [Error: Command failed: identify: unable to open image `����': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
identify: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
] code: 1, signal: null }
```

With the code below

```
   var request = require('request');
   var gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true}); // Enable ImageMagick integration.
   var imageType = require('image-type');

   request('http://c3.diapers.com/images/products/p/PG/PG-418_1z.jpg', function(error, response, body) {

        if (error) {
            console.error('unable to download image ' + err);
            return res.status(404).send('unable to download image ' + err);
        }

        if (!body)
            return res.status(404).send('no body response for image');

        var original = gm(body);
        original.size(function (err, size) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return res.status(500).send(err);
            }
            resize_photo(size, targetSize, original, function (err, photo) {
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
                res.send(photo);
            });
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was data was coming back as a string and not binary.  I have to set encoding:null in the request options and it worked after that.

[Getting binary content in Node.js using request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855015/getting-binary-content-in-node-js-using-request)