# Why is the downloaded image malformed?

Tags: node.js, jpeg, http-get, requestjs

Why is the downloaded image malformed?

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as request from 'request-promise-native';

const download = async (url) => {
  console.log(`Downloading ${url}`);
  const options = {
    url,
    resolveWithFullResponse: true,
  };
  const response = await request.get(options);
  console.dir(response.headers);
  return fs.writeFileSync('image.jpg', response.body);
};


const main = async () => {
  try {
    await download('https://dz2cdn1.dzone.com/storage/rc-covers/3339976-refcard-cover141.png');
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
};

main().then(() => console.log('success')).catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

The resulting image is malformed and can't be opened. Any ideas on what's causing the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting binary content in Node.js using request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855015/getting-binary-content-in-node-js-using-request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `request` treats the response as utf-8 text. If you want to preserve the response as binary (specifically as a single `Buffer`), you need to explicitly set `encoding: null` in your `request()` options.