# Node.js: use request module receive error bytes in http response

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using nodejs to send http request to a server, and get http response from it(the http response body is **encrypted**, while the http header is **normal**). The response body will be written to a file. But I find the response body is different from what the server sent.

This is what I've done:

```
request.post({
    headers: {'content-type':'application/json'},
        url:'url-to-server',
        body:data-to-send
    }, function(error, response, body){         
    if(!error && response.statusCode==200){
        fs.writeFile(path-to-file,body,function(err){
        });
    }
});
```

The problem is, some byte values are replaced by **`ef bf bd`**

```
Server Send:   
    f5 cb b6 48 77 b6 26 6a d2 4c d8 d9 ...
Received data: 
    ef bf bd cb b6 48 77 ef bf bd 26 6a ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you console.log(body)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've already done it, it just displayed messy code, because the http response body is encrypted.

Comment: you are calling a api using request , is this api same response when you call this from anyother source like postman or something else

Comment: can please try this once fs.writeFile(path-to-file,body, 'utf8', function(err, contents) {
    console.log(contents);
});

Comment: @SyedAyeshaBebe it prints _undefined_.

Comment: @ShekharTyagi As far as I know, `ef bf bd` has special meaning. Because the http body is in hex format(encrypted), so i'm wondering if this api cannot recognize some bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that `ef bf bd` occurs when it tries to use `utf-8` encoding. So I want to recieve raw data without encoding.

And I found [this question about getting binary content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14855016/3606247), according to this link, i add `encoding:null` in my code, see below:

```
    request.post({
        headers: {'content-type':'application/json'},
        url:'url-to-server',
        encoding:null,
        body:data-to-send
    }, function(error, response, body){         
        if(!error && response.statusCode==200){
            fs.writeFile(path-to-file,body,function(err){
            });
        }
    });
```

And now the received data is correct.