# Change response to binary

Tags: node.js, express, download, request, pipe

I am using this code to download image from google cloud storage using this code.

```
request(googleUrl).pipe(response);
```

My requirement is to change the image to binary and send over network.

P.S how to change the above code to promise as well.

Kindly please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting binary content in Node.js using request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855015/getting-binary-content-in-node-js-using-request)

Comment: FYI this is not a duplicate question. and request encoding did not work with pipe.

Comment: I tried this earlier and this was the response

Ignoring encoding parameter as this stream is being piped to another stream which makes the encoding option invalid.

Answer (score 0):

you can send binary file like below

```
const img = fs.readFileSync("imagePath");
res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "image/gif" });
res.end(img, "binary");
```