# Converted base64 image does not work, how can I get true base64 image?

Tags: node.js, base64, buffer

I try to convert my request payload to base64 but the result of my code is not a valid base64 image. When I try to use it in the browser, it doesn't display the image.

So I try to write simple code to convert image to base64 or using npm modules but the result is the same and I don't get a valid image!

```
const request = require('request');

const url = "http://cdn1.giltcdn.com/images/share/uploads/0000/0001/7250/172502872/420x560.jpg";

request({url, gzip: true}, function (err, res, body) {

    if(!err){
        const data = "data:" + res.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + Buffer.from(body, 'binary').toString('base64');
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

or

```
server.get("/test", function(req, res){
    const data = "data:" + req.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + Buffer.from(req.data.payload, 'binary').toString('base64');
    console.log(data);
});
```

The result is the same (when i copy and paste in browser, it doesn't display the image):

> data:image/jpeg;base64,/f39/QAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD9/QBDAAEBA...

When i used this https://www.base64-image.de/ website for converting to base64 image, the result is (when i copy and paste in browser, it works and displays the image):

> data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBA...

Why are the results different and why doesn't buffer to base64 work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need to set `encoding: null` as an option for the `request` function, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14855016/865038). It forces the `body` to be returned as binary instead of `utf8` which is the default.

```
const request = require('request');

const url = "http://cdn1.giltcdn.com/images/share/uploads/0000/0001/7250/172502872/420x560.jpg";

request({url, gzip: true, encoding: null}, function (err, res, body) {
    if(!err) {
        const data = "data:" + res.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + Buffer.from(body, 'binary').toString('base64');
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```