# Wrong decoded base64 utf8 image files

Tags: c#, node.js, base64

I'm using nodejs for getting base64 file but i`m do it in wrong way and i suddenly encoded base64 from utf8 charset. I want to recover my files that stored in db, I tested lot of ways to get back my data but the result is nothing.

My problem for uploading images solved in this question:

[Converted base64 image does not work, how can I get true base64 image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53126113/converted-base64-image-does-not-work-how-can-i-get-true-base64-image)

The sample stored image in my db is like this (Its png image with real size: 23275 bytes):

https://files.fm/u/vt5f5chn

please help me to recover my files with any tools or programming languages.

**Edit1:**

I used this code to store data in mongo:

In my server file (pure nodejs):

```
    // Get the payload,if any
    const decoder = new StringDecoder('utf-8');
    let payload = '';
    req.on('data', (data) => {
        payload += decoder.write(data);
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
        payload += decoder.end();
        req.data = {
            payload
        });
        // ... other codes
```

In my api that stored data in mongo:

```
const newAttachment = new TicketAttachment({
    name:fileName,
    type:fileType,
    size:req.data.payload.length,
    content:req.data.payload
});

newAttachment.save();
```

And image of data stored in my mongo is:

https://files.fm/u/vq9747zv

Comment: the base-64 decode works; however, the header is wrong - instead of  137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10, it starts 239
191
189
80
78
71
13
10 - the first 3 bytes are borked; trying to see why, but: what did you do to encode it? it is entirely possible that you have irreparably corrupted the data.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for helping me, its really big problem for me. I wrote Edit 1 to show my codes. please check it

Comment: @MarcGravell You are right about wrong bytes, i compared with true png image and i saw it.

Comment: It looks like you used an encoding backwards (so: tried to decode arbitrary bytes into a string). If you did that: the result is gibberish. Sorry, but: as I say - this could be toast.

Comment: 239 191 189 (EF BF BD) is U+FFFD aka the replacement character, which means that in the source there was unencodable character.

Comment: @ckuri, Is it means that i cannot recover my data?

Comment: Unfortunatelately this seems to be the case as it’s impossible to know which character was there originally.